# What is the meaning of "sandbox" in "docker run" command?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-registry

I am running the [Docker image with Apache Spark](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sequenceiq/spark/):

```
docker run -i -t -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.2.1-ubuntu /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
```

I can know the meaning of "`-i`", "`-t`" and "`-h`" after executing "`docker run --help`" command. But how can I explain the "`sandbox`" here? Is it a option of "`docker run`" command? I can't find it in the output of "`docker run --help`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that command, `sandbox` is the argument for `-h` option. So sandbox will be the hostname of the container you are creating. It has not any special meaning and could be any hostname you wish.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, you are right. I am tricked by "`sandbox`", haha...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The process launched by `docker run`has no access to the other processes on your host, this is more or less a sandbox. When you launch a docker container (say a webserver such as nginx), and you go inside with a `docker exec` you can do a `ps -ef` and you only see the processes of nginx and your `docker exec` not all the processes of your host

Comment: The format of "`docker run`" command is "`Usage: docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`", so the "`sandbox`" is `option`, right?

Comment: no the sandbox is you have no access to the processes of the host, your container process is isolated.